# Edit BOOTABLE ISO and retain MBR

Tags: boot-loader, iso, bootable

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a file from a bootable ISO on Debian Buster. Problem is: all the answers I can find via Google (no doubt there's more that don't show and this'll instantly be duplicate of a question whose answer yet again breaks the bootability of the ISO) break the bootability. This is a DOS bootable ISO, and I need to delete a file on the root of the ISO. mkisofs is out of the question as it's got info in the MBR I need to preserve, and mkisofs seems to have 0 ways to preserve the MBR. I've also tried ISO Master, which also breaks it. Any ways to delete this file from the ISO without breaking everything?

Comment: That installs a new MBR, and doesn't preserve the original. I need to preserve the original.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Something like ISO Master would work, and you can copy over the old ISO's MBR by doing

```
dd if=<original file> of=<modified file> bs=2k count=20
```

This copies the first few sectors of the old ISO on top of the new one, replacing the generated MBR with the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Add `conv=notrunc` to the dd command:

```
dd conv=notrunc if=<original file> of=<modified file> bs=2k count=20
```

Otherwise the target file will be truncated.